# Работа с байтами

Tags: java

Наш сервер соединяется к провайдеру данных по протоколу TCP/IP, после чего тот начинает присылать сообщения следующего формата:

```
[ LEN:2 ] [ TIMESTAMP:8 ] [ TICKER_LEN:2 ] [ TICKER:TICKER_LEN ] [ PRICE:8 ] [ SIZE:4 ]
```

где поля имеют следующую семантику:

```
LEN: длина последующего сообщения (целое, 2 байта)
TIMESTAMP: дата и время события (целое, 8 байт, milliseconds since epoch)
TICKER_LEN: длина биржевого тикера (целое, 2 байта)
TICKER: биржевой тикер (ASCII, TICKER_LEN байт)
PRICE: цена сделки (double, 8 байт)
SIZE: объем сделки (целое, 4 байта)
```

Как перевести данные с байтов в полноценое сообщение с стандартными типами данных?

Comment: Это формат строки ответа провайдера? Как вы к нему подключение организовали?

Comment: Да, это формат строки ответа провайдера. Подключение через сокет с указанием IP/

Comment: Т.е. сначала вы считываете с сокета 2 байта, затем 8 и т.д.?

Comment: Почему в одном случае целое - 2 байта, во втором - 8, в третьем - 4 байта? В Java целый тип int всегда занимает 4 байта

Comment: Все оказывается проще простого :

Comment: RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("data/nio-data.txt", "rw");
    FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();

    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);

    int bytesRead = inChannel.read(buf);
    while (bytesRead != -1) {

      System.out.println("Read " + bytesRead);
      buf.flip();

      while(buf.hasRemaining()){
          System.out.print((char) buf.get());
      }

      buf.clear();
      bytesRead = inChannel.read(buf);
    }
    aFile.close();

Comment: При получении ответа сервера и при чтении ответа ввиде байтов достаточно сделать приведение к типу char

Answer (score 2):

Есть замечательная библиотека JBBP, которая позволяет описать формат вашего бинарного протокола (прямо указав название поля, указать его тип (поддерживаются даже бытовые  последовательности)) и парсить ваш байтовый поток или массив удобно извлекая из него данные.